# POST request to a nested query - python API

Tags: python, mongodb, api, rest

So i've began to create a comment section for users to leave comments under posted events. I'm now trying to set up replies to comments under an event and am having issues. With the code I have, a new link is being generated but it isn't updating the dataset. Can anyone spot what I've done wrong?

```
@app.route("/api/v1.0/posts/<string:id>/discussions/<string:discussion_id>/reply", methods = ["POST"])
def add_new_reply(id, comment_id):
    new_reply = {
        "_id" : ObjectId(),
        "username" : request.form["username"],
        "comment" : request.form["comment"]
        

    }
    post.update_one( 
        { "_id" : ObjectId(comment_id) }, 
        
        { 
            "$push": { "reply" : new_reply }
        }
    )
    new_reply_link = "http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/posts/" + id + \
        "/comments/" + comment_id + "/reply/" + str(new_reply['_id'])
    return make_response( jsonify( { "url" : new_reply_link } ), 201 )
```

The structure of the post dataset is as follows:

```
Post

comment (array)
   
object

    reply (array)

    object
```

Comment: Don't post images of text

Comment: Ahh sorry, I didn't know that! I'll update that now :)

Comment: Where is `comment_id` coming from? You are searching `post._id` by `comment_id` but I am not sure if you can locate the record you want.

Comment: whoops, was a typo that I've updated now. it's in the parameters def add_new_reply(id, comment_id):

Comment: I think the issue is with the "$push": { "reply" : new_reply } line. I think I need to specify that reply is nested within the comment array, but am unsure how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confused between layering of objects. You can use below query to push to your `reply` array field

```py
post.update_one({
  "_id": <id of the post>,
  "comment._id": <id of the comment>
},
{
  $push: {
    "comment.$.reply": <your new_reply object>
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pGxCbxO8XjT)